# $\left(0,1\right]\neq\biguplus_{k=1}^{n}\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}G_{j},$ Proving elegantly

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

How can I show (without making many distinctions by cases) that the equality

$$
\left(0,1\right]=\biguplus_{k=1}^{n}\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}G_{j},
$$

can't hold, if $G_{j}\in\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ M^{c}\mid M\in\mathcal{A}\right\} $, where $$\mathcal{A}=\left\{ A\subseteq X\mid A\ \text{or}\ A^{c}\ \text{at most countably infinite}\right\} \cup\left\{ \left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]\mid n\geqslant2\right\}. $$

It seems obvious that it is true, but I couldn't find yet an approach to the proof, that makes it short and transparent.

( $+$ in the union stands for "disjoint union")

---

For the background: I arrived at this problem trying to find an example of an algebra on a set that is not a $\sigma$-algebra, but that contains a smaller  $\sigma$-algebra in it. Does someone maybe have a very easy (as in easy to state and easy to prove) example for this ?

Comment: (1) What is $X$? (2) If the sets $\bigcap_{j=1}^kG_j$ are pairwise disjoint, all but at most one are countable; is that what you intend?

Comment: Take an algebra over $X$ that is not a $\sigma$-algebra. It contains $\{\emptyset, X\}$, which is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: You have to use $G_{jk}$ instead of $G_j$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott 1) $X=\mathbb{R}$, sorry. 2) I don't understand "all but at most one are countable;". Could you please elaborate ? (This is what I intend, if that makes the equality true.)

Comment: If $\bigcap_{j=1}^kG_j$ is uncountable, it’s either a co-countable subset of $\Bbb R$ or a co-countable subset of some $\left[\frac1n,1\right]$. And two such sets have non-empty intersection.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I understand; I'm still not 100% sure though how you meant "all but at most one are countable" since I can take the union of just one set, so more than one set in $$T:=\biguplus_{k=1}^{n}\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}G_{j}$$ is uncountable. Actually, according to you, I believe $T$ countains all uncountable sets from $\mathcal{A}$, but nothing more. This would  also be the proof I needed, since $\(0,1\]$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$. Sadly, I can't "accept" your comment. (BTW; in my last comment I meant "...makes the equality **not** true", sorry)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not so sure anymore about your claim. When writing it out this morning, I got some doubts: Take $G_1:=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{\frac{1}{2} \}$, $G_2:=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{2\}$ and $G_3:=\[\frac{1}{n},1\]$,$G_4:=\[\frac{1}{n},1\]^c$ from $\mathcal{A}$ and $\{M^c \mid M\in \mathcal{A}\}$, for $n\geq 2$. Then $G_1 \cap G_3=\[\frac{1}{n},1\]\setminus \{\frac{1}{2} \}$ and $G_2\cap G_4=\[\frac{1}{n},1\]^c \setminus \{2 \}$. These sets are  uncountable and have *empty* intersection. They also don't lie in $\mathcal{A}\cup\{M^c \mid M\in \mathcal{A}\}$.

Comment: @user52145: I did make a mistake, but this isn’t it: I said that the intersection would be non-empty. I forgot that you’re including the complements of the intervals $\left[\frac1n,1\right]$, so you actually **can** get disjoint uncountable sets, e.g., $\left[\frac13,\frac12\right)$, and your disjoint union actually can make non-trivial sense.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. Anyway, using the ideas from the counterexample I gave above, I managed to figure out, how to proof it in a more or less clean manner.